# How to fetch user details by user name in multilingual website in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, multilingual

In my multilingual website i select arabic language.
I created a user from registration page.
Now if i login with that username following error comes:

```
Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int64.
```

I have created stored procedure given below:

**SQL:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserLogin]
    @UserName   NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  * FROM  Users WHERE UserName = @UserName
END
```

**ASPX CODE BEHIND:**

```
Dim UserName As String = "N'" & txtLogin.Text & "'"
Dim _dtLogin As DataTable = oUser.UserLogin(UserName)
```

**BUSINESS LOGIC:**

```
Public Function UserLogin(ByVal UserName As String) As DataTable
    _dbCommand = _database.GetStoredProcCommand("UserLogin")
    _database.AddInParameter(_dbCommand, "UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, UserName)
    _Dt = _database.ExecuteDataSet(_dbCommand).Tables(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Did you set breakpoints in your code and see what value is passed to your UserLogin and is it the UserName that is an issue or something outside of the above code?